# Variability of residuals

Tags: confidence-interval, modeling, residuals

Let assume we have a computer system that produces events in the form (x,y,z,e= (0|1)) where x,y,z are some states variables and e defines if some event happened or not. The random process generating those events follows an unknown distribution. Function F'(x,y,z) is our model and defines the probability of e happening.

I have millions of events which I bin by month and value of x then I calculate mean(e) and mean(F'(x,y,z)). Also for every bin I will calculate its residual (predicted - realised probability), at this point each bin has >10k, <100k events.

The results I receive are quite good but I see quite big variability in the residuals. For some months residuals are close to 0, for some I see 1% difference in probability in very few cases I see 10%. This variability disappears when I just bin by month and leave out x, in such cases each bin will have millions of events inside.

How I can capture/explain that variability in my residuals, maybe I can produce confidence intervals, maybe there are some other techniques which I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

One issue with your approach is that you aren't using a [proper scoring rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_scoring_rule). That is, your "residual" metric can't be expected to give the best scores to the models that give the most accurate probability estimates.

Furthermore, it sounds like you're using an aggregation scheme that allows errors in one direction to cancel out errors in the other direction, which is no good if you're trying to estimate the magnitude of error rather than the bias.